# cscope `Find this global definition:` not working while `Find this C symbol:` query works fine

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, cscope

I use this find command to generate the cscope file paths:

```
find /A/ /B/ /workingfolder/ \
    -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -o -name '*.idl' -o -name '*.cc' -o -name '*.hh' \
    > /workingfolder/cscope.files`
```

The folders `A`, `B`, `workingfolder` have all the source files I need. Then I use `cscope -i cscope.files -bq&` to generate the cscope database. I have a function called `foo` defined in a `.hh` file (it is a template and has a string specialization version):

```
template <typename T>
bool foo(T t) {
   do whatever;
}

bool foo(std::string s) {
   do another whatever;
}
```

When I invoke cscope with `cscope -d cscope.files`, `Find this C symbol: foo` can return a lot of results while `Find this global definition:foo` returns nothing. This is very weird to me. Can anyone help me why the `Find this global definition:foo` returns nothing? My cscope version is 15.6